# Play .ogg on command line

Tags: audio, music, command-line

How can I play a `.ogg` music file on the command line? On Linux I can use [ogg123](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ogg1231.html), but what about on Mac?

Answer (score 4):

You can still use **ogg123** through the [The Ogg Vorbis CODEC tools](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/audio/vorbis-tools/Portfile), installed through the [MacPorts Project.](http://www.macports.org)

Comment: It's seems good, i installed the vorbis-tools so how i play now? afplay not play and have no command ogg123.

Comment: On the first link I give you says that there's a configuration argument which is: `--enable-ogg123`. I guess you'll need to use it.

Comment: understood :), i dont know the macports very well, i try pass the argument like as follow: "sudo port install vorbis-tools configure.args=--enable-ogg123" but dont works, its correctly?